# How to store JS slideToggle in localStorage only for clicked button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several buttons including divs which they have the same name. unfortunately I can not change the names, they are generated by cms.

So for example when I click only on first button, only the first div is hidden or displayed, and that's fine.

But after refresh page it opens or closes all divs depending is the first div closed or opened, and that I do not want it.

here is the code:

```
<button class="a">Button</button>
<div class="target"></div>
<button class="a">Button</button>
<div class="target"></div>

$('.a').click(function() {
  $(this).next(".target").slideToggle(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('visible', $(this).is(":visible"));
  });
});

$('.target').toggle(localStorage.getItem('visible') === 'true');
```

here you can see jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/pj3gs0z9/3/

So my question is, is it possible to store only clicked button information, and after page refresh display or hide div from only clicked button ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but probably not in your case. If you tell us you can't change your button properties, and they are exactly the same, then you won't be able to store different data in your localStorage.

Isn't there any way where you can add some additional information to your button ? It could be a class, an id, a name, or even a `data-XXX` attribute.

By the way, how are your buttons generated ? are they hard coded, or fetched from a database, or ... ?

**EDIT**

Here is a way of adding different classes to all of your buttons (althoguh I recommend adding data attributes, but whatever floats your boat) :

```
let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button'); // Array of your buttons
let index = 0;
for (let button of buttons) {
  button.className += 'myCustomClass-' + ++index; // Add a custom class to your buttons
}

// Now in your local storage, you can store the class of the button !
```

**EDIT 2** I would store it like this :

```
// On click, in VanillaJS (sorry, haven't used JQuery in a while)
button.onclick = () => {
  let visibleButtons = localStorage.getItem('visible-buttons') || [];
  visibleButtons.push(button.className.match(/(myCustomClass-[0-9]*)/)[0]);
}
```

Comment: yes, i can add class for buttons. but maybe this could be a problem, because i dont know how many divs i will have. they are generated as needed. so maybe i will have 5 buttons and 5 divs, or maybe 2 buttons and 2 divs. is it possible to add diferent class for all buttons and divs ?

Comment: hey, thank you. please can you tell me how can i now store the class of the button ?

Comment: great thank you for the help. now i need to do that in jQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

This is one quick solution, but because of a `slideToggle` you gonna have a small flash of milliseconds of a visible div unless you first have them hidden and then based on `localStorage` display them.

```
$('.a').click(function() {
  $(this).next(".target").slideToggle(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('visible-' + $(this).index(), $(this).is(":visible"));
  });
});

$.each($('.target'), function(k, trg) {
  $(trg).toggle(localStorage.getItem('visible-' + $(trg).index()) === 'true'); 
});
```

Comment: Hi, this is working in jsfiddle. but for some unknown reason is not working here at http://phpbb32.majordroid.com/index.php

Comment: you need to click minus in close below, and plus to open. jus try and refresh page, and for some reason it closes all or opens all... :(

Comment: I don't seem to find your JS in the source of the Dev Tools. Are you sure it's there?